# flask-assets- FilterError: stylus: subprocess returned a non-success result code: 1, stdout=, stderr=

Tags: python, flask, stylus, webassets, flask-assets

I'm attempting to compile stylus files using flask-assets and webassets. This "just works" on the iMac in my office, but stylus is returning and exit code of 1 when I try to run the server on my desktop running Ubuntu 14.04.

I've tried installing stylus in the project directory and point STYLUS_BIN there, as well as installing stylus globally and setting STYLUS_BIN to 'usr/local/bin/stylus'. Either way produces an exit code of 1 when trying to run the server application. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Traceback -
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/879979fbc9ed3da92b54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the latest version of nodejs available in apt-get's default repositories is 0.10, which doesn not come with npm (it has to be installed separately).

I did `sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm node`, then followed the instructions here to add the Nodesource repositories to apt-get: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall

After installing nodejs 0.12 (which comes with npm), I did `npm rm stylus` and `npm install stylus`. Now my application loads correctly, including compling my stylus files to css.